# Object of class Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Trying to validate the field (assignee_id) if it is provided by the user.

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($data, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'description' => '',
        'assignee_id' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
            return ($request->input('assignee_id') != '');})|'UUID',
        'status' => [
            'required',
            Rule::in(['todo', 'done']),
        ],
        'id' => 'UUID',
    ]);
    $errors = $validatedData->errors();
    if($validatedData->failed()) {
        return response()->json($errors->all(), 400);
    }
```

**Error:**

```
ErrorException: Object of class Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf could not be converted to int in file /Users/ankurjaiswal/Documents/php-learning/task-manger/app/Http/Controllers/TaskController.php on line 21
```

Comment: why are you using the `|` operator, a bitwise operator, on the line with the error ?   hint hint, that is the problem

Comment: If the assignee_id is optional then you can simplify your rule as: ``assignee_id => 'nullable|UUID'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you mean to use 2 rules for `assignee_id`. Since you want to use a Rule object you would want to use an array to define the rules for this field:

```
'assignee_id' => [
    Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return ($request->input('assignee_id') != '');
    }),
    'UUID',
 ]
```

Though what you are doing with the `requiredIf` is a different story; as @OMi Shah has mentioned in the comments.